# Django : 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

I had a problem with my Django program. I'm a beginner in Django, I was looking for an answer with different posts with the same error than mine but no success ...

```
Here's my traceback :

Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/pod

Django Version: 1.11.2
Python Version: 2.7.13
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'labinit',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\django_learneo3\Learneo\labinit\views.py" in groupe_pod
  121.      if form.is_valid():

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in is_valid
  183.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in errors
  175.             self.full_clean()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  384.         self._clean_fields()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in _clean_fields
  396.                 value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in

 value_from_datadict
  639.         getter = data.get

Exception Type: AttributeError at /pod
Exception Value: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'
```

This issue appears since I have changed my **init** fonction, for the form that I use in my view :

Forms:

```
class Groupe_Form(forms.ModelForm) :    
    def __init__(self, nom_groupe, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Groupe_Form,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['pod'].widget = forms.Select()
        pod1 = Groupe.objects.filter(nom_groupe = nom_groupe).values_list('pod', flat = True)
        pods = list(pod1)
        self.fields['pod'].queryset = Pod.objects.filter(id__in=pods)
    class Meta:
        model = Groupe
        fields = ['pod']
```

Views :

```
def groupe_pod(request):

    global new_groupe
    grp = new_groupe
    form = forms.Groupe_Form(request.POST, grp)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            print "form was valid"
            data_groupe_pod = request.POST.get('grp_pod')
            print "data_groupe :", data_groupe_pod  

            global new_cours
            print new_cours 

            if new_cours == "ICND1":
                return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/icnd_1')
            elif new_cours == "ICND2":
                return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/icnd_2')         
    else : 
        form = forms.Groupe_Form(new_groupe)
    return render(request, 'pod.html', locals())
```

I've tried many things, I really don't know where is the problem in my Django code.

Comment: why are you passing the grp in the form? can you explain?

Comment: You should avoid using `global` in Python code. What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: @Exprator : I need grp in order to have a "dynamic" form. In the Model Groupe, I have a ManyToManyFields named "pod" relation with an other Model. For one Groupe object, I have selected "pods". I need to display in my form, the "pods" that I've selected and not all the "pods"

Comment: @Alasdair : I know that I have to avoid `global` in Python code but I need my different forms could communicate/interact each other according to the value that I select

Comment: You should not use globals to store data from one request (e.g. choices) that you use in another request. If you want to pass data from one request to the next you need to store it in the session, or include it in `request.POST`, the querystring or the url.

Comment: @Alasdair : I will check MiddleWare documentation for the session, maybe it is the solution. If I include the wanted data in `request.POST`, I just need to add the data to the arguments of the view, right ?

Comment: The [Session documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#examples) would be better than the middleware documentation. I don't know what you mean by "add the data to the arguments of the view".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form's `__init__` method is:

```
def __init__(self, nom_groupe, *args, **kwargs):
```

Therefore you should instantiate it with:

```
form = forms.Groupe_Form(grp, request.POST)
```

You currently have the arguments the other way round.

Comment: Thx, I have no error left but now my form doesn't work anymore ... I choose my selection and no response. It should pass to an other form ...

Comment: Try to debug the problem. Check the value of `form.errors` when the form is not valid. My guess is that your code with `globals` is not working - you're going to have to find a different way to pass data from one request to another.

Comment: `form.errors` displays `errorlist`. I have the wanted values in my forms

Comment: We've fixed the initial `AttributeError`, but you haven't provided enough information for me to help you any further. "No response" and "displays errorlist" doesn't explain what's going on.

Comment: sry I had the error 'Enter a list of values". It comes from this line I guess `self.fields['pod'].widget = forms.Select()`. When I comment this line, I have no longer this issue (but it is not the form that I want ...)

Comment: That still isn't really enough information. I don't know what the `pod` field is on your model. You might be better to ask a new question, since these issues are unrelated to your initial problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your `__init__` signature has as its first parameter `nom_groupe`. In `form = forms.Groupe_Form(request.POST, grp)` you pass `request.POST` as the first parameter. You have to switch the parameters:

```
form = forms.Groupe_Form(grp, request.POST)
```